# Manually trigger dropdown of CheckComboBox with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I have a CheckComboBox that I populate with data I grab from a website with the following method.

```
public void getCompanies() {
        // This method is called every time the user types a letter in the URLText box.
        // Grab data from the website and add the data to a list.
        HTMLParser p = new HTMLParser(URLText.getText());
        List<String> a = p.GetCompanyNames();
        // Remove old data so new data can be added.
        dropdownMultiple.getItems().remove(0, dropdownMultiple.getItems().size());

        for(String element : a) {
            dropdownMultiple.getItems().add(element);
        }
    }
```

This works just fine but I would like to have the CheckComboBox open the dropdown whenever this method is called.  I have a textbox overlayed on top of the CheckComboBox so the user can't click on it.  Ultimately I want it to look like an autocomplete dropdown that will dropdown whenever the user types in the text box.

In other words, how can I activate the dropdown event of the CheckComboBox without having the user click on it?

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Comment: it's a comboBox, isn't it? the trick is to read the javadoc up the inheritence tree: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#show()

Comment: @kleopatra I believe the OP is using a [`CheckComboBox`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html) from ControlsFX which, unfortunately, does not extend `ComboBoxBase`.

Comment: @Slaw ohh .. should have checked before commenting - thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about [`org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html). Unfortunately, it does not appear the library provides a way to programatically show the popup. But if you don't mind relying on implementation details there is a way to do what you want.

The `CheckComboBox`'s skin uses a JavaFX `ComboBox` internally. This latter class has a method named `show` that can be used to manually display the popup. You can get access to this `ComboBox` via a call to `Node.lookup(String)`.

```
CheckComboBox<String> box = new CheckComboBox<>();
((ComboBox<?>) box.lookup(".combo-box")).show();
```

*Note: This requires that the `CheckComboBox` is being displayed in a window.*

As a reminder, this deals with implementation details and can therefore break without notice. From looking at the source code this should work for both ControlsFX 8.40.14 and 9.0.0.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Is `".combo-box"` just the fx-id of the CheckComboBox?


Edit:

I see now.  It's just grabbing the combo-box selector.  That was dumb of me.  This worked perfectly, I'll select your answer.  Thank you so much for your help!